# Unselect a checkbox by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a checkbox which is unchecked always by default and users should not check it. I don't want to make the checkbox disabled as i want to pass the value of the checkbox when i submit the form. Please suggest.
The below code is not working:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" name="chkbox1" value="unChecked" checked="false" readonly="readonly">
```

With the above code checkbox is always selected, i want the checkbox always be unselected and users should not able to select it.I should not use the disable option too as i want to send the value of checkbox when i submit the form.Thanks.

Comment: An unchecked checkbox will not pass its value.

Comment: @Quentin then he can just assume it wasn't checked… it's a binary yes or no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `checked` attribute all together

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" name="chkbox1" value="unChecked" readonly="readonly" />
```

Setting the `checked` attribute with any string value (even false) makes the checkbox checked

---

> i want the checkbox **always be unselected** and users should **not able to select it**.I should not use the disable option too as **i want to send the value of checkbox when i submit the form**

It doesn't really sound like you want a checkbox at all, but just a hidden input that sends a value

```
<input type="hidden" name="chkbox1" value="unChecked" />
```

Comment: That doesn't actually fulfil the requirements of the question: "i want to pass the value of the checkbox when i submit the form"

Comment: I want to pass the value of the checkbox as well as user should not able to check it, but with the above code user can able to check the checkbox - @adeneo.

Comment: @user3684675 - but why do you need a checkbox when the user can't interact with it or change it, it makes no sense.

Comment: @user3684675 then disable the checkbox and pass its value with a hidden input, as adeneo explained above. Either way, this sounds like a flawed design.

Comment: Yes, at this situation it makes no sense but in future we have to implement it and till that time we need to pass the value once the form is submitted. @adeneo.

Comment: @user3684675 if you already know its supposed value (used isn't changing it), why are you passing it through your form? Just leave it out entirely for now and add this feature when you're fully ready to implement it.

Comment: Well, unfortunately you can't. A checkbox generally just passes `on` when selected, to tell the serverside code that the box has been checked, but you can add a custom value, but that value **will not** be sent to the server it the box is not checked, it's just that simple. so you have to do something else instead, and using a hidden input is how it's generally done.

Answer (score 0):

`checked` attribute sets the checkbox to checked status, no matter what value the attribute `checked` has.

```
checked="checked"
checked="true"
checked="false"
checked=""
```

all these set to checked status

so there is no way to unset the checkbox (except some js solution) manuelly except for completely dropping the checked attribute

**UPDATE**: Simply change disabled to readonly, so that user cannot check it, but you still can submit this field with form

Comment: readonly was my first option, it is not working ,users can check the checkbox even if i give the option readonly. @doniyor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new so I can't leave a comment. But according to my understand to your problem, like@adeneo suggested, why not first use a hidden one that does pass a value for the "do" with the program; then put up a dummy disabled one for the "look" with the users? As you only need it for the moment? Then later you just hide the dummy one and show the real one?

Comment: Thanks all , i will proceed by using hidden field as suggested, thankyou.